# How can I parse a nested TJSONObject in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

My Delphi application calls a REST API, which produces the following JSON:

```json
{
   "status": "success",
   "message": "More details",
   "data": {
      "filestring": "long string with data",
      "correct": [
         {
            "record": "Lorem ipsum",
            "code": 0,
            "errors": []
         }
      ],
      "incorrect": [
         {
            "record": "Lorem ipsum",
            "code": 2,
            "errors": [
               "First error",
               "Second error"
            ]
         }
      ],
   }
}
```

I now want to work with the data, but I am unable to receive the information stored in the `data` section. Currently I am trying to receive the data like below:

```pascal
var
   vResponse : TJSONObject;
   vData : TJSONObject;
begin
   // .. do other stuff ..
   vResponse := // call to REST API (Returns a valid TJSONObject I've wrote it into a file)
   vData := vResponse.get('data'); // throws error
end;
```

But this leads to the following error:

> Incompatible Types: TJSONObject and TJSONPair

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TJSONObject.Get()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Get) returns a `TJSONPair`, not a `TJSONObject`.  You will have to either:

- use the [`TJSONPair.JsonValue`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONPair.JsonValue) property:

  ```pascal
  var
    vResponse : TJSONObject;
   vData : TJSONObject;
  begin
    // .. do other stuff ..
    vResponse := // call to REST API (Returns a valid TJSONObject I've wrote it into a file)
    vData := vResponse.Get('data').JsonValue as TJSONObject;
  end;
  ```
- use the [`TJSONObject.GetValue()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.GetValue) method, which returns just the `JsonValue` of the found `TJSONPair`:

  ```pascal
  var
    vResponse : TJSONObject;
    vData : TJSONObject;
  begin
    // .. do other stuff ..
    vResponse := // call to REST API (Returns a valid TJSONObject I've wrote it into a file)
    vData := vResponse.GetValue('data') as TJSONObject;
  end;
  ```

Comment: That's not really getting at the nested data, is it? Or, am I missing something? I had hoped to see how to get the value of, for instance `['data']['incorrect']['code']`

Comment: It is just the 1st step. Repeat the step over and over for each nested value as needed. So, `Get/Value` the `data` object, then `Get/Value` its `incorrect` object, then `Get/Value` its `code`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rene. I figured out some code and posted it [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/delphi/comments/zuj7k0/how_can_i_parse_a_nested_tjsonobject_in_delphi/) in the hope that it might help others.  The code could be polished, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

> Incompatible Types: TJSONObject and TJSONPair

The error message is self explaining: `vData` is declared as `TJSONObject`, which means that the return type of the `Get` function is `TJSONPair`.

To fix such errors you need to change the declaration of the result variable. In this case that would mean declaring `vData` as `TJSONPair`.

However, if you are not interested in getting a pair, but instead `TJSONObject`, you need to use other ways to retrieve it. For instance the `Values` property. Because `Values` returns `TJSONValue` you need to typecast it to `TJSONObject` if you know that the value is an object.

```
vData := vResponse.Values['data'] as TJSONObject;
```

Comment: Or you get the object as property:
     vdata:= vresponse.values['data'].asObject;
      writeln(objtostr(vdata));
      >>>TJsonObject2@094F3E10